# I can't activate VIsual SVN on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn

I was using the trial version of VisualSVN until recently. When it expired, my employer purchased a license key which I entered by clicking on `Registration` on the VisualSVN menu.

However, even after doing this, all of the VisualSVN options are still greyed out, both in the toolbar and the context menu.

I have tried repairing Visual SVN, uninstalling and reinstalling it and repairing Visual Studio 2010, still no joy.

Have I missed a step in setting this up?

Comment: Which version of VS2010 are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2010, the trial worked perfectly for me!

Comment: I've got VSVN 2.0.6 on VS2010 Pro running. is yours similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had trouble with the registration of VisualSVN.
I have tried this method and resolved my problems. Follow these steps.

1. Uninstall the previous installation of VisualSvn
2. Search in the registry the path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VisualSVN and remove it
3. Search in the registry the path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VisualSVN and remove it
4. For x64 remove the path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VisualSVN
5. Reinstall VisualSvn and register your license

Pay attention. If you have installed *VisualSVN Server* on the same development machine then, in the paths above, you will find also the info used by *VisualSVN Server*.
These **should not** be removed....

As always, when you mess with the registry editor, make a backup copy of everything you touch and be very very careful on what keys press to.
Of course I can't be sure that this resolve your problem, I'd like to know.

Comment: Glad I helped. I also had this problem and it was really annoying

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.